# Parse and print from related group of data

Tags: python

Within a file (example data below) there are groups of similar output in which we search for specific text in a line. Within each group of text, if the `issuerID` and `subjectID` are both present, print those two items along with the `sourceIP` and `destIP`. If not, skip and move on to the next. The code below works, but I am looking to add logic to only print the desired information if the `issuerID` and `subjectID` are a match.

Here is the current iteration of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

sourceIP = 'Source IP:'
destIP = 'Destination IP:'
issuerID = 'Issuer ID:'
subjectID = 'Subject ID:'
for line in open('data.txt', 'r'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(sourceIP):
        sourceIPline = line
    elif line.startswith(destIP):
        destIPline = line
    elif line and line.startswith(issuerID):
        issuerDomain = re.search("www[\w.com]+", line)
    elif line and line.startswith(subjectID):
        subjectDomain = re.search("www[\w.net]+", line)
        print (sourceIPline)
        print (destIPline)
        print issuerDomain.group()
        print subjectDomain.group()
        print
```

If I run the code with the data-set below which a value doesn't meet meet the criteria, I get an error. I would prefer this group is ignored and move on.

```
$ ./dparser.py
Source IP: 10.0.0.126
Destination IP: 8.8.8.8
www.domain.com
www.domain.net

Source IP: 10.0.0.126
Destination IP: 8.8.4.4
www.domain2.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dparser.py", line 22, in <module>
    print subjectDomain.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Here is a sample data-set with two groups.

```
-------------------------------
Template ID is 45841
Application Label: 443
Source IP: 10.0.0.126
Destination IP: 8.8.8.8
Source Port: 38946
Dest Port: 443
flowStartTime: 2013-12-30 20:20:21
flowEndTime: 2013-12-30 20:21:37
flowEndReason: 3
Protocol: 6
Octet Total Count: 8497
Rev Octet count: 28802
Packet Total Count: 30
Rev Packet Total Count: 32
TCP Sequence Number: 561150853
Initial TCP Flags: S
Union TCP Flags: APF
Reverse TCP Sequence Number: 4118697381
Reverse Initial TCP Flags: AS
Reverse Union TCP Flags: APF
SSL Server Cipher: 49171
-- X.509 Cert 0 (v.2) ---
        Issuer ID: 3 Val: www.domain.com
        Subject ID: 3 Val: www.domain.net
        Valid Not Before: 131015000000Z
        Not Valid After: 140211235959Z
        Public Key Length: 0
--- End of Cert 0 ---

-------------------------------
Template ID is 45841
Application Label: 443
Source IP: 10.0.0.126
Destination IP: 8.8.4.4
Source Port: 42529
Dest Port: 443
flowStartTime: 2013-12-30 20:20:22
flowEndTime: 2013-12-30 20:21:37
flowEndReason: 3
Protocol: 6
Octet Total Count: 8341
Rev Octet count: 26678
Packet Total Count: 27
Rev Packet Total Count: 30
TCP Sequence Number: 3052048930
Initial TCP Flags: S
Union TCP Flags: APF
Reverse TCP Sequence Number: 101975511
Reverse Initial TCP Flags: AS
Reverse Union TCP Flags: APF
SSL Server Cipher: 49171
-- X.509 Cert 0 (v.2) ---
        Issuer ID: 3 Val: www.domain2.com
        Subject ID: 3 Val: Some Subject
        Valid Not Before: 130727000000Z
        Not Valid After: 140118000000Z
        Public Key Length: 0
--- End of Cert 0 ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate your regex found something. In this case the second data set does not have a domain but instead says "Some Subject".

You want something like:

```
if subjectDomain:
    print subjectDomain.group()
else:
    print line  # whatever you want here...
```

Also, your regex is not defined correctly anyways. The [] symbols make a group of things to check. You really want r'www.\w+.com' otherwise you are allowing 'wwwww' and 'www.w.w'.

Comment: Reading this again, I realize I was not completely clear. `[A-Z]` means match any char from A-Z. `\w` is roughly the same as `[A-Za-z0-9]` plus some non-English characters. `[\w.com]` means `\w` or `.` or `c` or `o` or `m`.